# Measurement Protocol does not appear in google analytics real time

Tags: http, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I send similar requests and they do not appear in Google Analytics REAL TIME section 
I followed this guide :  [Measurement Protocol Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide)

But apparently I'm missing something

```
Remote Address:213.57.23.44:80
Request URL:http://www.google-analytics.com/collect
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:173
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:www.google-analytics.com
Origin: {domain}
Referer: {reffer}
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)             Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
v:1
tid:UA-XXXXXXXX-X
cid:42
t:screenview
an:Go Vegan
aid:org.anonimus.govegan
aiid:com.android.vending
ea:home
el:viewMode :categories
sc:421398881844730
sr:320x480
ul:he
```